# Find the table for custom attribute values

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, eav, custom-attributes

I’ve installed magento edition version 1.9.2.0 and added a custom attribute `catalog_special_name` (text field) and i want to know which table stores the custom attribute values for each product.

Answer (score 22):

When you create an attribute for a product, EAV (Entity Attribute Value) comes into the picture. To get a value you need to know the basic ways Magento stores EAV data.

For this, the following tables play important roles:

1. **eav_attribute**

   Whenever you create an attribute, this table gets entry which stores all the important data that helps to make a relation, such as `entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, `backend_type` and many more (but these are the important fields).
2. **eav_entity_type**

   Magento has 8 types of entity by which the type of attribute is decided. In your case it is `catalog_product`.

   1. `customer`
   2. `customer_address`
   3. `catalog_category`
   4. `catalog_product`
   5. `order`
   6. `invoice`
   7. `creditmemo`
   8. `shipment`

### How do we determine it's `catalog_product` in your case?

When you create a new attribute there will be an entry in the **eav_attribute** table. If you check this entry there will be a column `entity_type_id` whose value is 4, which matches up to `catalog_product` from the **eav_entity_type** table.

The **eav_attribute** table also has a column known as `attribute_code` which is nothing but the value of Attribute Code entered while making a new attribute from admin.

Since, in your case, we find that it's `catalog_product`,  we can look for all tables whose names start with `catalog_product_entity`. You will get tables whose endings are like `datetime`, `decimal`, `text`, `varchar`, `int` etc.

**catalog_product_entity** is the primary table for products. Our product id is nothing but the value of `entity_id` in this table.

### How do we know which `catalog_product_entity_*` table to use?

In the **eav_attribute** table, there's a column `backend_type`. This tells us which table to use to find the values. In your case it might be `varchar`, so we would look for the **catalog_product_entity_varchar** table. In this table we can search for an `attribute_id` and an `entity_id` (which is a product id and which we can see in the admin grid and which is equal to `entity_id` in the **catalog_product_entity** table).

### It's time for a practical!

Suppose your product id is 13 and your attribute code is `catalog_special_name`.

So in the **eav_attribute** table we will search for a record whose `attribute_code` is `catalog_special_name`. This will give us useful information:

```mysql
> select attribute_id,entity_type_id,backend_type from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'catalog_special_name';
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
| attribute_id | entity_type_id | backend_type |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
|          138 |              4 | varchar      |
+--------------+----------------+--------------+
```

So as `entity_type_id` is 4, we will look in the **eav_entity_type** table and confirm that our attribute is for `catalog_product`.

```mysql
> select entity_type_code from eav_entity_type where entity_type_id = 4;
+------------------+
| entity_type_code |
+------------------+
| catalog_product  |
+------------------+
```

So our entity type is `catalog_product` and our backend type is `varchar`, so we use the **catalog_product_entity_varchar** table. Here we will search for a record whose `attribute_id` is 138 and `entity_id` is 13 (our product id), and that's it!

```mysql
> select value from catalog_product_entity_varchar where attribute_id = 138 and entity_id = 13;
+-----------------+
| value           |
+-----------------+
| Office Supplies |
+-----------------+
```

There are still some other important tables. For more details on EAV you can follow:

- [http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-eav-database-structure/](https://web.archive.org/web/20180814172126/http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/09/07/magento-eav-database-structure/)
- http://inchoo.net/magento/magentos-database-layout-and-its-eav-structure/
- http://divante.co/blog/efficient-magento-code-database-flat-eav-part-1/
- [http://magecert.com/eav.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20180820193827/http://magecert.com/eav.html)

Comment: @ Ashish Madankar : If my custom attribute author,, how can i find author values in db

Answer (score 5):

Short answer ... make use of `getBackendTable()`

```
$code = 'catalog_special_name';
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $code);
```

For text attributes `echo $attribute->getBackendTable()` will return ...

> {prefix_}catalog_product_entity_varchar

---

Since `eav_entity_type` can change do **not** use static numbers like `catalog_product` = `4` or use fixed attribute IDs.

```
$attribute->getEntityTypeId()
$attribute->getAttributeId()
```

Same for entity names, instead of `catalog_product` you can use `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY`

If you want the filter by EAV attributes `entity_type_id`, do not use

```
$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', 4)
```

Better get correct `entity_type_id` from DB first ...

```
$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/config')
    ->getEntityType(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY)
    ->getEntityTypeId();
```

Comment: How to find which table hold attribute id = 56? Thanks @sv3n

Answer (score -1):

If you have the email of customer, you can probably try this list of queries:

1. Get the customer entity id: (Ex: 10)

   **SELECT entity_id FROM `customer_entity` where email='user@example.com'**
2. Get the attribute id of attribute code: (Ex: 225)

   **SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute` where attribute_code='my_attribute'**
3. Get the value of the customer attribute, "my_attribute":

   **SELECT value FROM `customer_entity_varchar` where attribute_id=225 and entity_id=10**

Comment: how to get the select attribute ? in which table it stores?

Answer (score -2):

In the database if you use the flat tables 
you can find your attribute in to the `catalog_product_flat_1` table.

further more all attribute  are store in the  `eav_attribute` table.
you can find your attribute in this table with attribute_id and use it to get more info.