# Magento getCollection

Tags: database, magento-1, product-attribute

I'm new to magento, Can any one told me Where "celebrity" & "base_color" values stored in DB ?

1-

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('celebrity', array('neq' => 'no_selection'))
```

2-  **URL Parameters**  `.../?filter=Black&code=base_color`

```
$collection= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                           ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                           ->addFieldToFilter($_GET['code'],array('eq' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                           ->getAttribute($_GET['code'])
                           ->getSource()
                           ->getOptionId($_GET['filter']))); 
                        ->load();
```

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/117720/45103

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some things you still have yet to learn about Magento.

One of those is how EAV works. Magento's EAV system stores values for attributes (like in your case, "Celebrity" and "base_color") in multiple tables depending on the type of data being stored.

However, all of these values are in tables with a prefix of: `catalog_product_entity`

in our prefix + `_int` integer values are stored. in our prefix + `_varchar` varchar values are stored.

It can get pretty complicated so I would just look at it and check it out as well as do some more research.

You can see all of the available attributes listed in the table: `eav_attribute`

As for your second question:

To get the parameters from a url you need to be working in a controller and then run this code:

`$this->getRequest()->getParam('my_param')`