# How to get min/max value of attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation

I want to get min and max value of a product attribute(as width of a carpet) from database in order to create a slider range on my layered navigation filter, do you know which table stock those informtaion? 
Thank you

Comment: what type of attribute is it ? could you please provide more details where and how you want to use and which module are you using

Comment: product attribute as length or width for a carpet for example , i4m not using a module, i want to gt min and max in order to create a slider for the default layed navigation filter (I updated my question , sorry)

Comment: you should read this post answer, it will give you detail answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117694/find-the-table-for-custom-attribute-values/117704